# How can I find all placeholders for str.format in a python string using a regex?

Tags: python, regex

I'm creating a class that renames a file using a user-specified format.  This format will be a simple string whose `str.format` method will be called to fill in the blanks.

It turns out that my procedure will require extracting variable names contained in braces.  For example, a string may contain `{user}`, which should yield `user`.  Of course, there will be several sets of braces in a single string, and I'll need to get the contents of each, in the order in which they appear and output them to a list.

Thus, `"{foo}{bar}"` should yield `['foo', 'bar']`.

I suspect that the easiest way to do this is to use `re.split`, but I know nothing about regular expressions.  Can someone help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In case you know all possible variables *beforehand*, you can just pass them all to `str.format` - it will ignore those not in pattern. `'{user}_{bar}'.format(user='Mike', foo=1, bar=2)` will output `Mike_2`. I happend to have allowed vars fixed in a dict, so I could skip  looking for vars in pattern. Anyway knowing about `string.Formatter()` is useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using `re.findall()`:

```
In [5]: import re

In [8]: strs = "{foo} spam eggs {bar}"

In [9]: re.findall(r"{(\w+)}", strs)
Out[9]: ['foo', 'bar']
```

Comment: Just a quick question.  Are the results from `re.findall` guaranteed to be listed in the same order as they appear in the string?

Comment: @blz yes, as the string is parsed from left to right.

Comment: Beware, this does not account for format specifiers such as `{spam:3f}`. @DSM's answer should be the accepted one. Modifying the `\w` to include more characters until it matches the full spec of `str.format` could work, but using the formatter itself is better (and not prone to breakage if the syntax evolves)

Answer (score 64):

Another possibility is to use Python's actual [Formatter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.parse) itself to extract the field names for you:

```
>>> import string
>>> s = "{foo} spam eggs {bar}"
>>> string.Formatter().parse(s)
<formatteriterator object at 0x101d17b98>
>>> list(string.Formatter().parse(s))
[('', 'foo', '', None), (' spam eggs ', 'bar', '', None)]
>>> field_names = [name for text, name, spec, conv in string.Formatter().parse(s) if name is not None]
>>> field_names
['foo', 'bar']
```

or (shorter but less informative):

```
>>> field_names = [v[1] for v in string.Formatter().parse(s) if v[1] is not None]
>>> field_names
['foo', 'bar']
```

and the reason why we need the `is not None`

```
>>> [v[1] for v in string.Formatter().parse("a{b}c")]
['b', None]
>>> [v[1] for v in string.Formatter().parse("a{b}c") if v[1] is not None]
['b']
```

Comment: oooooh... I like this!  I'll probably accept Ashwini Chaudhary's answer because I specifically asked for a regex solution, but I think I'll use yours since I understand it a bit better!  Thank you!

Comment: Can this be modified to find `%(name)s` placeholders?

Comment: This is the right answer in my opinion. Uses the same mechanism as .format() do.