# Reverse of Python string formatting: generating a dict from a string with named parameters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this, where `symbol` and `property` vary:

```
a = '/stock/%(symbol)s/%(property)s'
```

I have another string like this, where `AAPL` and `price` vary:

```
b = '/stock/AAPL/price'
```

I'm trying to generate a dict like this:

```
c = {
    'symbol': 'AAPL',
    'property': 'price'
}
```

With string formatting, I could do a this:

```
> a % c == b
True
```

But I'm trying to go the other direction. Time for some regex magic?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want your dictionary to be `D = {'APPL' : price}` so you can look up price by symbol? Otherwise you will need a new dictionary for each stock.

Comment: I'm assuming (unlike other answers so far) that your first-string doesn't *necessarily* say `symbol` and/or `property`, e.g., it might read `/zog/%(evil)s=%(level)s,%(flavor)s`.  Is that the case?

Comment: Do you have control of the format of `a`?  If you use a more modern interpolation style, certain things become easier.

Comment: @DSM I might be able to control it. What format would be easier?

Comment: By control, I mean the ```%(symbol)s``` part. The slashes aren't changeable.

Comment: @nathancahill: well, if it were '/stock/{symbol}/{property}', I mean.  Then you could use `string.Formatter` to extract the names without regex, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14061832/487339).

Comment: The names, yes, but I still think a solution like @Ashwini's would be needed to extract the name-value pairs.

Comment: @torek Yes, that's the case, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to @moliware's solution, but there's no hard-coding of keys required in this solution:

```
import re

class mydict(dict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self.setdefault(key, '')
        return ''

def solve(a, b):
    dic = mydict()
    a % dic
    strs = a
    for x in dic:
        esc = re.escape(x)
        strs = re.sub(r'(%\({}\).)'.format(esc), '(?P<{}>.*)'.format(esc), strs)
    return re.search(strs, b).groupdict()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = '/stock/%(symbol)s/%(property)s'
    b = '/stock/AAPL/price'
    print solve(a, b)
    a = "Foo %(bar)s spam %(eggs)s %(python)s"
    b = 'Foo BAR spam 10 3.x'
    print solve(a, b)
```

**Output:**

```
{'symbol': 'AAPL', 'property': 'price'}
{'python': '3.x', 'eggs': '10', 'bar': 'BAR'}
```

As @torek pointed out for cases with ambiguous output(no space between keys) the answer can be wrong here.

For eg.

```
a = 'leading/%(A)s%(B)s/trailing'
b = 'leading/helloworld/trailing'
```

Here looking at just `b` it's hard to tell the actual value of either either `A` or `B`.

Comment: Note: you'll need `dic=mydict()` and I get `'/stock/None/None'` as the value in the call used to populate `dic`.  I'd just do `dic = collections.defaultdict(str)` though.  (Oops, you fixed the missing `dic=` part while I was typing the comment.)

Comment: BTW this works really well (it's the way to go here) but there are indistinguishable variations for which this just picks "any solution that works", e.g., `a = 'leading/%(A)s%(B)s/trailing'` and `b = 'leading/helloworld/trailing'`.  This chooses `A='helloworld'` and `B=''`.  (And if string `b` is cannot be generated by format `a` regardless of dictionary values, the `re.search()` returns None.)

Comment: @torek Good test case, I think this one can be considered ambiguous too because `B` can be either `''` or `'helloworld'` or `a` can be `''` or `'helloworld'`.(So a space or some other character is required between two keys to get correct answer).  Another issues is returning a `str` for missing keys would raise error for %d or other directives, I am not sure how to fix that.

Comment: @torek I think I could use a couple of try-except blocks to catch those type mismatch errors and pass some other default value.

Comment: The last example won't be a problem, there will always be some sort of delimiter between keys.

Answer (score 4):

A solution with regular expressions:

```
>>> import re
>>> b = '/stock/AAPL/price'
>>> result = re.match('/.*?/(?P<symbol>.*?)/(?P<property>.*)', b)
>>> result.groupdict()
{'symbol': 'AAPL', 'property': 'price'}
```

You can adjust a bit more the regular expression but, in essence, this is the idea.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming well-behaved input, you could just split the strings and zip them to a dict

```
keys = ('symbol', 'property')
b = '/stock/AAPL/price'
dict(zip(keys, b.split('/')[2:4]))
```

Comment: I came up with the letter-for-letter same solution. `str.split` is almost always going to be many times more time-efficient than the `re`-based equivalent.

Comment: @KirkStrauser - yeah, there's a hundred ways to parse strings, but I like the simple solutions.

Comment: As long as it's *always* slashes, and slashes don't appear in the output from some key(s).  If the output might begin with, e.g., `/nyse/stock/` (vs say `/ftse/stock/` and just `/stock/`) sometimes, you'd need to adjust the indices too.  In short, much depends on input constraints.

Comment: @torek - agreed. As more details of the input are learned, the script could be updated. But split and the dict constructor are fast, so its a good start.